# openssl_pkcs7_sign returns nothing while signing Passbook's pass file

Tags: php, openssl, passbook

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign('manifest.json', 'signature', $certdata, $privkey, array(), PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED, 'AppleWWDRCA.pem');
```

It makes a empty signature file and no error message.

But I can use OpenSSL command line to make a right signature(uses same copy of WWDR, p12, pkpass files):

`openssl smime -binary -sign -certfile AppleWWDRCA.pem -signer passcertificate.pem -inkey passkey.pem -in manifest.json -out signature -outform DER -passin pass:123123`

Comment: What PHP version? What OpenSSL version? Is it the same version as PHP's using? Check `phpinfo`.  Is `error_reporting` cranked all the way up and are you either checking the error log or have the `display_errors` ini setting enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of your $certdata and $privkey, if they are filenames, prefix with 'file://'.

As @Charles says, your error logs are the best place to look for clues as to why it is failing.

We used to use the following command, but after benchmarking we found exec was performing better.

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign( 
    "manifest.json",
    "signature",
    "file://" . $certdata,
    array("file://" . $privkey, $keyPassword),
    array(),
    PKCS7_BINARY|PKCS7_NOATTR|PKCS7_DETACHED,
    "/path/to/AppleWWDRACA.pem");
```